# php не находит 1 и 2й индекс. PHP make table

Tags: php, циклы, отладка

Решил для себя поставить первое "большое" задание после "Hello World" в PHP сделать таблицу, которая будет вытягивать значения из php файла (2 часть это запись в файл с страницы). Наконец-то запустил дебагер, но пока еще не разобрался в нем (

---

Код должен из этих данных, что сейчас написаны в txt файле построить таблицу 3x3!
Код говорит, что не находит 1й и 2й индекс в **$mass**! Но выводит значения в 1 строку без _ и без ;. В коде страницы он даже не добавляет почему-то html код таблицы.
Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка в коде?

---

file.php

```
<?php
  $string1=file("table.txt");
  for($i=0;$i<count($string1);$i++){
    $datatxt=explode(";", $string1[$i]);
      for($i=0;$i<count($datatxt);$i++){
        $mass=explode("_",$datatxt[$i]);
        $name=$mass[0];
        $surname=$mass[1];
        $age=$mass[2];
        echo "<tr><td>".$name."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$surname."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$age."</td></tr>";}}
?>
```

---

table.txt

```
Angela_First_16;Lily_Oto_18;Ann_Girl_31;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка в индексах выводится из-за того что при разбивке строки `Angela_First_16;Lily_Oto_18;Ann_Girl_31;` создается массив $datatxt состоящий из 4-х элементов, не 3-х.
Удалите последний знак `;` из файла так `Angela_First_16;Lily_Oto_18;Ann_Girl_31`.

Можете сами убедится:

```
<?php
$string1=file("table.txt");
for($i=0;$i<count($string1);$i++)
{
  $datatxt=explode(";", $string1[$i]);
  for($j=0;$j<count($datatxt);$j++)
  {
    $mass=explode("_",$datatxt[$j]);

    print_r($mass);

    $name=$mass[0];
    $surname=$mass[1];
    $age=$mass[2];

    echo "<tr><td>".$name."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$surname."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$age."</td></tr>";
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, заработало!)

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте во втором цикле переменную $i на $j например

Comment: Вроде бы это не обязательно (ведь переменная внутри)?!

Comment: @ALPHA и что, что внутри? Зона видимости то одна. Ну и в ответе DevelOper, если обратили внимание, это учтено